# Replication fails when Subscriber's Firewall is On

Tags: sql-server-2008, tcp, windows-firewall, transactional-replication

Our SQL Server 2008 PUBLISHER (Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2 64-bit) fails to replicate to our SQL Server 2008 SUBSCRIBER (Windows Server 2008R2 SP1 64-bit) when the subscriber's Public Firewall is turned On; however, when the Firewall is turned Off, replication works immediately.  This Transactional Replication with a Distributor (push subscription) has been running well for three years with the subscriber's firewall off. We need to turn the firewall ON now.

Both machines are in the same LAN (same physical rack) and are up to date on Windows Updates. Subscriber's TCP Ports (80, 443, 1433, 1434, 21, 135, 139, 445) and UDP Ports(137,138,1434) are allowed to "Any". I have disabled TCP Chimney Offload and the Boost SQL Server priority is off on Subscriber.

Following is what I get from PUBLISHER's replication log when it fails to replicate:

```
Command attempted:
if @@trancount > 0 rollback tran
(Transaction sequence number: 0x00001E920000B5EB000100000000, Command ID: 1)

Error messages:
TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)
Get help: http://help/0
TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 121)
Get help: http://help/121
Communication link failure (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 121)
Get help: http://help/121
Communication link failure (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 08S01)
Get help: http://help/08S01
```

What am I missing? How can I fix this issue? :s

Answer (score 0):

I RESOLVED this issue! I am writing to share my solution hoping it helps someone as well.

All I needed to do is leave empty (or blank out if there is a value) the property TCP Dynamic Ports, while leaving TCP Port with 1433 on the Subscribers.

That is, on Subscriber, go to SQL Server Configuration Manager > TCP/IP > IP Addresses > IP All and perform the change. After doing that change, I restart (at Subscriber still) on SQL Server Services: SQL Server, SQL Server Browser, SQL Server Agent, SQL Server Reporting Services.